# Problems with cin and reading input

Tags: c++, cin

I am new to C++ and I have a problem with `cin` in my code.

When I run this code, after I enter some words, it just skips and ignores the second `cin` in the code and I don't understand why.

I read that it happens because of <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd> in the new line, and I should use `cin.ignore()`, but it still does not work. For the first loop, I use <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> and loop ends my problem after that.

```
int main() {
        vector<string> words;
        cout << "Enter your words" << endl;
        for (string input; cin >> input;) {
            words.push_back(input);
            cin.ignore();
    
        }
        cout << "You entered these words:" << endl;
        for (string a: words) {
            cout << a << endl;
        }
        cin.ignore();
        string disliked;
        cout << "If you have any disliked word please type it " << endl;
        cin >> disliked;
        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            if (words[i] == disliked) {
                    words[i] = "Bleep";
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: `for (string input; cin >> input;) {` what exactly do you expect that loop to do? How do you end inputting words?

Comment: with ctrl+z in pc

Comment: If you Ctrl+Z then you can't use cin anymore. cin is now in a failed state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (string input; cin >> input;) {
    words.push_back(input);
    cin.ignore();
}
```

So, as you say in a comment, the user ends this loop by entering *end of file* (ctrl-Z on Windows console). After that, the file is at end. You can not continue reading from it, it is closed.

You have to figure out some other way to end this first loop. Suggestions:

- Instead of reading words, read lines usint `std::getline`, and if user enters empty line, then end this loop. You then have to split the line into words as a separate step, of course.
- Add some specific non-letter "word" to mark the end of this loop, such as a lone `"."`.

---

Also, as long as you are reading words with `std::cin >> word`, you don't need `std::ignore()` for anything. Reading into an `std::string` will skip any leading whitespace automatically.